# CodenameOne How-to set app name and app icon

Tags: codenameone

does anybody know how-to set the app name and the app icon shown in Android's app list using CodenameOne?

Kind regards,
  Uwe

Answer (score 3):

right click on your project and select project property

[image]

make sure your image 512x512

you can set application name next textfield to the Title (as shown in the image)

For android/iOS specific property click on IOS or Android below the CodenameOne in Tree.

sometime Google Search will give you the answer faster than asking question on Stackoverflow.

Cheers.

Comment: Notice that we are migrating to the new UI which is accessible via the right click as well under Codename One -> Codename One Settings